# AngularJS JSON Compression

Tags: php, javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to figure out a way to pipe a compressed JSON string from the server to the front end.  On the backend, I am simply using gzcompress to compress the returned string from json_encode.  Is there a javascript function that can uncompress a string that was compressed using gzcompress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uncompress and run this code on client side, the following code has to be included in the HTML code:

```
<script src="./jsxcompressor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
eval(JXG.decompress(jxgcompressed));
</script>
```

see this link [gc compressed](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wp/2009/09/29/jsxcompressor-zlib-compressed-javascript-code/)